# ConnectException on remote execution via JSch

Tags: java, jsch

My aim is to remotely run a command using JCraft's JSch library. The code snippet is given below. I'm getting a `java.net.ConnectException`. My ulterior purpose here is to run a batch file remotely from my system.

Code Snippet:

```
String command = "ipconfig"; //Or any execution command
String host = "10.10.*.*";
String user = "username";
String password = "password";

JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);;
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();
session.setHost(host);

UserInfo userInfo = new MyUserInfo();
session.setUserInfo(userInfo); 
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
channel.setInputStream(null);
((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
channel.connect();

System.out.println("Channel Connected to machine " + host + " server with command: " + command ); 


try{
    InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
    String line = null;

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    inputReader.close();
```

Error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed   out: connect
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at RemoteExecution.execute(RemoteExecution.java:125)
at PutFilesToUnix.main(PutFilesToUnix.java:127)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
... 4 more
```

Comment: Can you connect to the `10.10.*.*` from the same machine using a standalone SSH client?

Comment: Your code breaks at the connection attempt. Verify that you can connect with same credentials with PuTTY manually.

Comment: Yes,I'm able to get a response when I ping the IP from cmd. Pardon my naivety if that is not what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see connection timeout/ session timeout property in your code. Try to add session timeout parameter probably that would help.Not sure if you don't set those parameter how long connection can wait to connect. Also Try to download any open source clients and see if you are manually able to connect.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!